# The difference of search logic in the RefNbr field on the Bill and Adjustments screen between 2017 R2 version and 2021 R2 version of Acumatica System

Tags: customization, acumatica

I have some questions about the business logic of RefNbr Searching functionality in Bill and Adjusments screen of Acumatica System.
In 2017 R2 Version, if I write some number in RefNbr field, system will show all related RefNbr and order by descending. Please the following screenshot.

[image]

But in latest version (2021 R2 version), it shows all related RefNbr but seems like using Ascending sort order.

[image]

Is it possible if I try to customize to provide as logical same as 2017 R2 version for this latest version  ?
If it's possible, in which class and method should I customized ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the RefNbr declared attributes.  Be sure to set the Search sorting order to descending.

```
    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXDefault()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Reference Nbr.", Visibility = 
    PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible, TabOrder = 1)]
    [APInvoiceType.RefNbr(typeof(Search2<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.refNbr,
    InnerJoinSingleTable<APInvoice, On<APInvoice.docType, 
Equal<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.docType>,
And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.refNbr>>>,
InnerJoinSingleTable<Vendor, On<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.vendorID, Equal<Vendor.bAccountID>>>>,
Where<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.docType,Equal<Optional<APInvoice.docType>>, 
And2<Where<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.origModule, NotEqual<BatchModule.moduleTX>, 
Or<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.released, Equal<True>>>,
And<Match<Vendor, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>, 
OrderBy<Desc<Standalone.APRegisterAlias.refNbr>>>), Filterable = true, IsPrimaryViewCompatible = true)]
        [APInvoiceType.Numbering()]
        [PXFieldDescription]
            public string RefNbr { get; set; }
```